# Divide 8-bit integers by 4 (or shift) using SSE

Tags: c++, x86, sse, simd, intrinsics

How can I divide 16 8-bit integers by 4 (or shift them 2 to the right) using SSE intrinsics?

Comment: i think just specifiying the correct -march or -mtune makes it happen automagically: https://godbolt.org/g/jxGyFd

Comment: First of all that tool is awesome for Q&A pages like StackOverflow. I immediately bookmarked it. And for the real content of answer, thanks I'll have a look at the assembly, if the compiler does it automatically for some case I should be able to read it out of the assembly anyways.

Comment: @RichardHodges I find that code fairly disappointing actually, Clang does a good job though.

Comment: @harold why disappointing? remember that it's dealing with the pathological case of the block not being aligned on an SSE-compatible boundary. Once it handles the edge cases, the main block is vectorised.
If you marked the pointers as being aligned I'm sure you'd see perfect code.

Comment: Hmm, no, annotating the pointers with a 16-byte alignment doesn't help GCC. It turns out that the *real* difference is that `mtune=native` is causing Clang to assume AVX2 support, whereas GCC is assuming only AVX support. If you explicitly pass `-mavx2` to GCC, you get much better output that resembles Clang's. Clang's, of course, doesn't change. A good lesson in why "native" doesn't make much sense for an online compiler whose system specs you don't control. :-) @richard

Comment: @RichardHodges the fixup isn't the problem, the main SSE-using part is. It converts to words (which is in the first place not necessary and causes significant loss of throughput), and then it emits useless `vpand`'s (which would have been useful if it hadn't converted to words, but it did, so the only reason I can see for them is that GCC is scared of the saturating pack and couldn't figure out that it would be harmless)

Comment: @harold I see. Perhaps it's just not a popular use case so has not caught the attention of the code generator maintainers?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unfortunately there are no SSE shift instructions for 8 bit elements. If the elements are 8 bit *unsigned* then you can use a 16 bit shift and mask out the unwanted high bits, e.g.

```
v = _mm_srli_epi16(v, 2);
v = _mm_and_si128(v, _mm_set1_epi8(0x3f));
```

For 8 bit *signed* elements it's a little fiddlier, but still possible, although it might just be easier to unpack to 16 bits, do the shifts, then pack back to 8 bits.

Comment: Thanks, just solved it myself by writing a macro which fakes epi8: ```#define _mm_srli_epi8(mm, Imm) _mm_and_si128(_mm_set1_epi8(0xFF >> Imm), _mm_srli_epi32(mm, Imm))```

Comment: @miho: Note that there aren't really any advantages to writing this as a macro instead of an inline function here.

Comment: @DietrichEpp: actually some compilers complain if the `Imm` in `_mm_srli_epi32 ` is not a literal constant (particularly in debug builds), which can be a problem with inline functions, although you should be fine with current/recent versions of gcc, clang, ICC.

Comment: Ah yes, of course.  There are still other ways you can avoid macros here.

Comment: Yes, it depends whether your code needs to be portable and work with a bunch of different compilers, in which case you have to play to the lowest common denominator (MSVC usually). If you only need to work with one (or a few) compiler versions then you can probably get away with an inline function here.

Comment: @PaulR The hack that I use is to make the shift amount a template argument.